# What charting technology is being used on nextbigsound.com?

Tags: javascript, charts

It's looks like they are using an all javascript based solution.

Are they using a package out there are did they roll their own solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey! Samir from Next Big Sound here, we are indeed using a custom implementation raphaeljs. This tutorial is great: http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they are using a custom implementation of [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).